# iPhone sdk how to receive string value?

Tags: iphone, string, plist

In my application, i need to provide three languages support. My default language will be English. Once the user selects other language in setting controller the entire application should change into that particular language. For this i decided to have a plist file with all the three languages and their data in it.Now my default language is English that is fine. Now i changed the language using plist in LanguageController and pushed to home controller. The selected language(French) string was not received in my home controller. Here is my code,

```
//LanguageController.h

NSMutableDictionary *allDictElements;
NSString *selectedLanguage1;
NSArray *dummy;

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary *allDictElements;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *selectedLanguage1;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *dummy;

 //LanguageController.m

@synthesize allDictElements,selectedLanguage1,dummy;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSString *path= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Language" ofType:@"plist"];

    allDictElements = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"%@allDictElements",allDictElements);

    LeeValleyHomeViewController *homeController = [[LeeValleyHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LeeValleyHomeViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

     if (indexPath.row ==0)
     {
        //bookshelf button
        NSMutableDictionary *english=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        english=[allDictElements objectForKey:@"English Language"];
        dummy=[english objectForKey:@"English"];
        selectedLanguage1=[dummy objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"english bookshelf button:%@",selectedLanguage1);
        homeController.selectedLanguage = selectedLanguage1;  
        NSLog(@"sel lang:%@",homeController.selectedLanguage);

     } else if (indexPath.row ==1) {
        //bookshelf button
        NSMutableDictionary *french=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        french=[allDictElements objectForKey:@"French Language"];
        dummy=[french objectForKey:@"French"];
        selectedLanguage1=[dummy objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"french bookshelf button:%@",selectedLanguage1);
        homeController.selectedLanguage = selectedLanguage1;
        NSLog(@"sel lang:%@",homeController.selectedLanguage);

    } else {

        NSMutableDictionary *spanish=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        spanish=[allDictElements objectForKey:@"Spanish Language"];
        dummy=[spanish objectForKey:@"Spanish"];
        selectedLanguage1=[dummy objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"spanish bookshelf button:%@",selectedLanguage1);
        homeController.selectedLanguage = selectedLanguage1;
        NSLog(@"sel lang:%@",homeController.selectedLanguage);
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:homeController animated:YES];
}
```

Here in this controller am receiving the selected language string finely.

```
//LeeValleyHomeViewController.h

NSString *selectedLanguage;

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *selectedLanguage;

 //LeeValleyHomeViewController.m

@synthesize selectedLanguage;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    LanguageViewController lvc = [LanguageViewController alloc]init];
    bookshelfbtn.titleLabel.text = lvc.selectedLanguage1;
    NSLog(@"button title:%@",bookshelfbtn.titleLabel.text);
   //bookshelfbtn.titleLabel.text = selectedLanguage;
}
```

Here in this controller am not receiving that string value. What's wrong with my code? or how can i do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain if "`LanguageController`" you have in the first block of code is the same thing as "`LanguageViewController`" in your second block of code.

But if it is, why do you think the "`selectedLanguage1`" property would be set to anything other than zero after you instantiate that "`LanguageViewController`"?  The user hasn't touched any cell yet so the only language that it could possibly be is English (with a value of value zero).

Comment: Yes. I knew it. After the user selected the language from "LanguageViewController" it must change the language right?

Comment: Yep.  You also need to keep your "`LanguageViewController`" around for a while.  Make it an ivar in your "`LeeValleyHomeViewController`" object.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the selected language in NSUserDefaults and retrieve it in ViewDidLoad of LeeValleyHomeViewController.m   like this.....

In your,

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

  {

  //  after selecting language

  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:selectedLanguage1 forKey:@"language"];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

  }

//LeeValleyHomeViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

```
NSLog(@"button title:%@",bookshelfbtn.titleLabel.text);
bookshelfbtn.titleLabel.text =  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey forKey:@"language"];

}
```

Comment: Yes am receiving the selected language string now. But my button is empty(no text) while loading...

Comment: try This,  bookshelfbtn setTitle:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey forKey:@"language"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: no its still empty while loading...i cleaned the build and checked it now.